# How to contramap over functions?

Tags: haskell, contravariance

Given:

```
class Contravariant (f :: * -> *) where
  contramap :: (a -> b) -> f b -> f a
```

The following code is rejected. I'm expecting to get `String -> Bool` (a predicate) as a result of contra-mapping `Int -> Bool` over `String -> Int`. I feel stupid as I must be making some wrong assumptions. Please help me in understanding the error message. Why is the second argument expected to be different than the one I think I need?

```
Prelude Control.Lens> contramap length (>0) "Hello"

<interactive>:25:19: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Bool’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: [Char] -> Int
        Actual type: [Char] -> Bool
    • In the second argument of ‘contramap’, namely ‘(> 0)’
      In the expression: contramap length (> 0) "Hello"
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = contramap length (> 0) "Hello"
```

Comment: What is the `Contravariant ((->) a)` instance?

Comment: @Alec: There is none, because the parameter is used in positive position.

Comment: @Alec Ah. Welp.  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contravariant only works on the last argument of a type constructor. You might want `Profunctor`, which denotes type constructors that are contravariant in the second to last argument and covariant (like a regular Functor) in the last one.

```
<Gurkenglas> > lmap length (>0) "hello"
<lambdabot>  True
```

Comment: After some reflection, I think I like this answer better than mine! It emphasizes the same intuition that the person asking the question probably had, and addresses the issue of first type argument/second type argument for `Contravariant` which is probably the actual misunderstanding that happened in the asker's mind.

Comment: Oh. I thought that a concrete `Bool` would be inferred by GHC somehow. But it remained as a "free variable" on the type level. In other words I thought I was working with `newtype Predicate a = a -> Bool` which I believe actually is contravariant. My `contramap length (Predicate (>0))` now type checks.

Comment: @sevo It's about (type) argument position, not about variable vs. non-variable. The concrete `Bool`ness is indeed inferred by GHC. Consider also `newtype Predicate b a = Predicate (a -> b)`, which will still happily be a `Contravariant` instance.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you're looking for the boring old covariant `Functor` instance.

```
> fmap (>0) length "Hello"
True
```

At an even higher level, you may be looking for the [`null`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null) function. For many types, `length` will traverse the entire data structure you pass to it, whereas `null` generally will not.

Here is a short explanation of the error message, as well. First:

```
contramap length :: (Contravariant f, Foldable t) => f      Int  -> f (t a)
(>0)             :: (Num a, Ord a) =>                (->) a Bool
```

I have aligned things in what I hope is a suggestive way. In order to apply `contramap length` to `(>0)`, we would need to set `f ~ (->) a` and `Int ~ Bool`. The second is clearly impossible, so the compiler complains. (N.B. The first equation is only subtly impossible; even if you supplied a function which returned an `Int` you'd have a problem, but the compiler doesn't notice yet because the obvious problem with the second equation trumps it. Namely: there is no `Contravariant` instance for `(->) a`, and can't be!)

Comment: Which is of course `(.)`: `fmap (> 0) length = (> 0) . length`